# How to fetch data from multiple tables using view in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

this is my view :

```
CREATE VIEW  Statistic as
SELECT
  (SELECT
     COUNT(0)
   FROM users) AS `tot_user`,
  (SELECT
     COUNT(0)
   FROM demands) AS `tot_demand`,
  (SELECT
     COUNT(0)
   FROM reports) AS `tot_report`,
  (SELECT
     COUNT(0)
   FROM users
   WHERE users.mobile_verified_at IS NULL) AS `user_inactive`,
  (SELECT
     COUNT(0)
   FROM reports
   WHERE reports.state =0) AS `report_inactive`,
  (SELECT
     COUNT(0)
   FROM demands
   WHERE demands.state = 1) AS `demand_inactive`,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM replies LEFT JOIN demands ON demands.id=replies.id) AS `demand_replied`
```

i wanna fetch data where 
created_at( column )  between date1 and date2

this is my tables structure :

[image: demand table]

[image: user table]

**And so are the other tables

for example : i want fetch records that created between 2019-12-01 and 2020- 01-01

request(data1 and date 2 from the server) -> send ->database | Database => Return this view

Comment: 'wanna fetch data where created_at( column ) between date1 and date2' - thats pretty much the syntax so what problem are you having?

Comment: for example : i want fetch records that created between 2019-12-01 and 2020- 01-01

Comment: Add proper WHERE to each separate subquery.

Comment: "TSQL" and MySQL refer to different databases.  I'm confused by the title.  The code suggests MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You want to compare a timestamp to a date so use date function

```
where date(created_at) between '2019-12-01' and '2020-01-01'
```

and do review mysql date functions. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html